# Where are all of the missile max upgrades?

Tags: cave-story

Due to the use of late game topics, spoilers as follows.

I want to see how quickly I can kill the Doctor, and I want to get enough missiles to destroy both forms of him. Through the game, I came across enough missile max upgrades to get it to 25 (only got 20, skipped the zombie sky dragon one). Are there any other ones I can collect, and if so, where are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 5 missile expansions that bring you up to a grand total of 54 missiles. The first 4 on this list give you 5 missiles each, while the last "Bonus" upgrade gives you an additional 24.

> **Grasstown**
>
> Right above the building with the motorbike outside/door that needs to
>   be destroyed by a bomb.
>
> **Grasstown**
>
> Inside the grasstown hut just above the shelter where Kazuma was
>   locked in.
>
> **Egg Corridor**
>
> After returning to Egg Corridor. By the sky dragon in where egg 12
>   used to be.
>
> **Egg Corridor**
>
> After returning to the Egg Corridor. Inside the Egg Observation Room
>
> **Bonus Missile Expansion**
>
> Located in the Sacred Grounds secret stage in a chest hidden in a
>   single star block located high on a ledge just before the room with
>   Heavy Press boss fight.

**Source:** http://wikicheats.gametrailers.com/Cave_Story_-_PC/Max_Missile_Expansion_Locations